# Does factory reset for Cisco ASA 5505 keep the added licenses/features?

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-asa

I bought a used Cisco ASA 5505 with existing SecurityPlus (and other) licenses already installed.

A factory reset (configure factory-default) from the console will reset just the config and not erase the added license keys, correct? I don't have access to the original keys (they were installed by the previous owner) and don't want to lose access to these extra features.

I'm new to Cisco products and don't want to bork it doing something silly.

Comment: https://community.cisco.com/t5/firewalls/security-license-gone-help/td-p/2143680 this post suggests if full reset then you'll lose it. but it could be recoverable. unless overwritten flash in full.

Comment: Thanks - this is the (few) scenarios I've found on the web also. It seems that if you *format* the flash you lose everything but I would assume "configure factory-default" wouldn't do that. I'll back up the hex key first anyway. Surely someone else in stackland has performed this and knows for sure. Otherwise I'll have to call Cisco.

Comment: @peleion - I confirm that configure factory-default does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't loose your licenses.
A reset to factory default only deletes the startup-config.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments and answer.

I can confirm that the Cisco ASA 5505 indeed does *not* lose the activation key/license when performing the factory reset. No action is required after the factory reset - it boots back up with the key intact.